# Quitar estilo desde un clon dependiendo de su Posicion (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Único detalle: Cómo quito estilo desde los elementos clonados en #campoBusq
a su elemento proveniente? que esta en:

> *#cateoria>.cont-optionElement>.elemento ".$contador.*

¿que métodos podría tomar para este problema?

**Usuario Plantilla.php**

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div> 

<div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
        <div id="categoria">';
            include("selectCategJquery.php");
            <div class="mensCateg">Selecione las Categorias</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**selectCategJquery.php**

```
<?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    $contador = 0;
    while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $contador++;
        $varHtml .='<div class="cont-optionElement">';
            $varHtml .= "<div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento ".$contador."' iden='".$contador."' >". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</div>";
        $varHtml .='</div>';
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
?>

<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");
               $.ajax({url:'selectCategJquery.php',method:'post',data:{"identificador":identificador}});
               var div = $('<div/>', {
                                'class' : 'xClones',
                                'html' : '<span>X</span>'

                            });


               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
                    $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove();
                    $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
                }else{
                    $(e).append(div);
                    $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
                    $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").addClass("estilSelectCateg");
               } 
           });


            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $( $(".cont-optionElement")[0]).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
                    // var  $identificador=$_POST['identificador'];
                     // $(".cont-optionElement").find("."+identificador).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");


            });

        });
  </script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este me funciona $( $(".cont-optionElement")[0]).removeClass("estilSelectCateg")‌​; pero tendria que marcar manualmente las posiciones y busco un tipo contador

Comment: Intente Usando $ajax para pasar la variable desde jquery a php pero no se si esta mal el codigo

Comment: quieres que cuando un elemento de #categoría se clone en #campoBusq, el original aparezca sin estilo?

Comment: En este codigo hay una funcion que clona como acabas de entender, pues el detalle es que cuando se crea esa clonacion, el elemento de categoria se le añasira un background para indicar que ese elemento esta clonado..( es como un checkbox).. ok ... luego de estar clonado, quiero que; cuando le den click al elemento clonado en #campoBusq, remueva el estilo de categoria

Comment: En qué momento estás declarando $varHtml? Qué hace un llamado ajax por post al mismo script donde estás parado, si no usas nada de su salida?

Comment: el ajax no esta terminado, queria pasar la variable identificador de jquery a php para eliminar el estilo mediante el clon con el mismo identificador de  donde fue clonado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta ejecutando esta solución que te propongo, en la cual no uso PHP para crear las categorías, solamente simulo las categorías ya creadas de acuerdo al código que estás planteando.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
    var e = $(this).clone();
    var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");
    $.ajax({url:'selectCategJquery.php',method:'post',data:{"identificador":identificador}});
    var div = $('<div/>', {
      'class' : 'xClones',
      'html' : '<span>X</span>'

     });


    if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
   $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove();
   $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
  }else{
   $(e).append(div);
   $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
   $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").addClass("estilSelectCateg");
    } 
   });


 $('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {
    var identificador = $(this).parent("#elementoBusq").attr("iden");  
  $("#categoria").find("." + identificador).parent().removeClass("estilSelectCateg");   
$(this).parent().remove();
 });
});
```

```css
#campoBusq{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:blue;
  padding:5px;
}
.estilSelectCateg{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Categorias seleccionadas:</div>
<div id="campoBusq"></div> 
<br />

<div class="mensCateg">Selecione las Categorias:</div>
<div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
        <div id="categoria">
            <div class="cont-optionElement">
              <div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento 1' iden='1' >Categoria 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cont-optionElement">
              <div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento 2' iden='2' >Categoria 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cont-optionElement">
              <div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento 3' iden='3' >Categoria 3</div>
            </div>            
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No amigo; esto no me srve porque es una pagina donde manejare sentencia de sql desde un usuario ROOT para no estar modificando el codigo .. por ejemplo si yo quiero insertar una nueva categoria lo que hara solamente es crear interfaces que se encarguen de ejecutarlas y listo. entiendes lo que te digo

Comment: Lo que te entiendo es que no te sirve por que las categorías se crean dinámicamente a través de un página destinada para esto (o sea un CRUD). Si esto es correcto, no te preocupes, solo pon el código php de tu vista donde los necesites. Por que el problema que planteas (hasta donde entiendo) es una problematica de css y JavaScript, así que el tema de sentencias SQL no debería ser un impedimento para que esta solución te pueda ayudar en algo. De todas maneras sigamos compartiendo los conceptos, para tratar de solucionar tu inconveniente.

Comment: te digo que el sql si tiene que ver un poquiito no mas y es que; en cada elemento de categoria que se encuentre en sql te mostrara los div el cual hay que asignar identificadores para poder identificarlos y que al darle click se elimine el estilo pero solo el que coincida con su identificador, me entiendes este punto en donde el sql esta un poco relacionado

Comment: Correcto, entonces tú lo que debes hacer es que la porción del HTML donde tengo las categorías preestablecidas lo reemplazas con tú código PHP `include("selectCategJquery.php");`. Yo no pongo ese código en la respuesta es para que tú puedas ver como está funcionando la solución cuando le das click al botón ´Ejecutar´ al final de la respuesta. Por que si ejecutas la respuesta podrás visualizar como funciona la solución que te propuse.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente mano gracias pero ahora  tengo una confucion sobre la variable que se creo nuevamente

Comment: Ya entiendo amigo, que mal  estuve, no habia entendido que el find busca como caracteres y yo tratando de pasar los valores de identificador como variables desde jquery a php X-(,

Comment: gracias haz ganado tu recompensa y gracias a todos por su tiempo de verdad

Comment: Que bien!!! me alegra que hayas solucionado tu necesidad.

Comment: espero que valores esta pregunta para hacer mas recompensas mas adelante ya uqe mi proyecto es muy largo y mas que estoy aprendiendo directamente jquery con ustedes porque sin ayuda me costara mas usar jquery

Answer (score 3):

Voy a darte una idea de como resolverlo, probablemente no sea la mejor, pero te puede guiar o puede permitir a otro usuario colaborar más profundamente (con más tiempo).

> El objetivo es obtener el índice (posición) del elemento con clase `xClones` que está siendo seleccionado respecto a todos los demás `xClones`, y a continuación quitar una clase al elemento con el índice correspondiente entre los elementos con la clase `cont-optionElement`

Usando entonces jQuery (la única etiqueta en la pregunta), y tomando como base el código que ya tienes:

```
$('#campoBusq').on('click','.xClones',function() {

  // obtenemos el índice del elemento
  var clonIndex = $('.xClones').index($(this));

  $(this).parent().remove();

  $( $(".cont-optionElement")[clonIndex]).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");

  // ...
}
```

Comment: se ve mue logico, apenas lo pruebe te respondo

Comment: Amigo ya probe el codigo y funciona pero hace un comportamiento extraño y es que; si seleciono todas las categorias solo se remueven el estilo cuando le doy xclones desde el ultimo que se seleciono al primero es decir; se eliminan de manera desendente

Comment: si trato de quitar los estilos de manera aleatoria algunos me lo remueve y otras no. repito solo se eliminan de manera desendente

Comment: se acaba el tiempo de la recompensa

Comment: Tal y como te dije, es una idea que puedes tomar como punto de partida, lamentablemente no tengo tiempo en este momento de profundizar más en el tema. Haz un poco de depuración y seguramente podrás terminar de resolverlo.

Comment: amigo tu explicacion me quedo sonando al pensar que de esta manera puede funcionar correctamente si gustas, cuando tengas tiempo me ayudas a corregirlo y te dare puntos por el codigo cuando lo publiques

Comment: El problema es que al dar click en xclose de modo del ultimo a la primero en ese orden es que se eliminan de resto no lo hace, es como si se perdiera el posicionamiento de los elementos que index establecio al buscarlos